# Uninstall non-loaded extension from Safari

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, simbl

When opening Safari I get this error:

[image]

Now I want to uninstall this extension, however it doesn't show up in the Extensions preferences:

[image]

How do I uninstall this?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like an extension, but a SIMBL Plugin.

These can be found in the directiory `/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins`, and you should be able to remove the `SafariOmnibar.bundle` from there.